# How to "Always" show an element, which is only visible on hover?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to modify the "Quick View Feature". I want it to "always" display, without any hover effects.

I've tried using the opacity CSS but didn't work for me.

```
.quick-view {
opacity: 1;
}
```

I want to achieve it with only CSS, Is it possible with only CSS?

Comment: Try using: `visibility: visible`

Comment: Here is the link https://spendr.dk/shop/

Comment: @ManishPatel 

I just tried the "visibility: visible" but nothing happened. 

Here is the link for your reference: https://spendr.dk/shop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is show using `transform` css, So just remove `transform` form it's css.

```
.grid-tools.hover-slide-in {
    transform: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options
1: Eliminate the the other css or javascript code that is modifying the element.
(you can search it with the class name, id name or whatever in css or html).

2.= use display:

```
.quick-view {
display: block; /* can also use flex, or inline-block whatever*/
}
```

3.- use visibility:

```
.quick-view {
visibility: visible;
}
```

regards!